# Use UIAlertAction to increment badge on Tab Bar with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
 @IBAction func addToCart(sender: AnyObject) {
    let itemObjectTitle = itemObject.valueForKey("itemDescription") as! String

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Add \(itemObjectTitle) to cart?", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)

   let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) in

        var badgeNumber = 0

        self.navigationController!.tabBarItem.badgeValue == "\(badgeNumber++)"

    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(yesAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

I need the selection of "Yes" on the alert to increment a badge on a Tab Bar Item every time it is pressed, has anyone had this problem?

Comment: In your `yesAction` method, update the controller's `.tabBarItem.badgeValue` string to however many items are in the cart.

Answer (score 2):

```
let yesAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default) { action in
      // Your code to update the tab bar here
}
```

Alternative:

```
UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", 
              style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, 
            handler: { // Code goes here 
})
```

Comment: Right, that's what I meant my intentions were pure

Comment: Once I added the { action in } after the yesAction method it throws an error saying Could not find member .Default I'm stumped

Comment: I appreciate the quick answer, different error this time. 

Cannot find initializer for type 'UIAlertAction' that accepts an argument list of type '(title: String, style: UIAlertActionStyle, handler: (_) -> _)'

Comment: Okay I've edited my code so it builds now. Badges are still not appearing...I know I need to select the tab bar item at index(1)